# Looping correlations in matrix columns in R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have a 200x200 matrix of simulated models and want to calculate the correlation between certain columns. Here's some of the data:

```
     var1          var2        var3         var4   
[1,]  0.000000000  0.0000000000  0.00000000  0.000000000 
[2,]  0.081707812 -0.4674752956 -0.09885623  0.311421458 
[3,]  0.104660320 -0.5066112338  0.16215542  0.224543735  
[4,]  0.148780552 -0.2419104721 -0.01707375  0.122405936
```

I'm trying to find the correlation between var1 and var2, var3 and var4, var5 and var6 and so on. Outputting the correlations into a 100 length vector would be amazing.

I had the data split into 100 200x2 matrices named R1, R2 etc. and was using this code

```
for(i in 1:100){
     cor[i] <- cor(get(paste0(R,i,))[,1], get(paste0(R,i,))[,2])
}
```

But it returned an error

```
 Error in paste0(R, i, ) : object 'R' not found
```

Storing the data into one matrix is obviously preferable to one hundred, but I'm an absolute novice at R and can't figure out how to do this after searching.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way with your example:

```
x <- matrix(c(0.000000000, 0.0000000000, 0.00000000, 0.000000000, 
              0.081707812, -0.4674752956, -0.09885623, 0.311421458,
              0.104660320, -0.5066112338,  0.16215542,  0.224543735,  
              0.148780552, -0.2419104721, -0.01707375,  0.122405936), 
              4, 4, byrow = TRUE)

out <- cor(x)
diag(out[c(1,3), c(2,4)])
#[1] -0.5784471 -0.0925900
```

You can then expand to your 200x200 matrix:

```
out <- cor(x)
diag(out[seq(1,200,2), seq(2,200,2)])
```